# Chatbots queries

Tags: artificial-intelligence, watson, dialogflow-es

Recently I'm learning about the Conversational AI concept. I've gone through an overview of Dialogflow and Watson, but I need to know about few things such as

```
    1. Delivery models
    2. Qualitative and quantitative metrics on delivery of conversational AI
    3. Tools used for testing these Intelligent chat bots
    4. Simulators or any other testing frameworks available
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: But I need answers for all those questions,which fall under same category "Conversational AI".Instead of asking multiple questions,I made it into a single question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not designed for these types of questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  For answers on the Watson part you can try asking on DWAnswers https://developer.ibm.com/answers/index.html . Someone else might be able to help you on dialogflow.